# Gradient of tf.floor is None

Tags: python, tensorflow

`tf.floor` return None gradient
it means the weights before `floor` operation won't be update, right?
but I still need the gradient to update weights
Isn't it weird? sometimes we use `floor`, `ceil`... but they can't deliver gradient or this is right action
as well as `tf.cast`, the gradient return none

Here is an issue [#897](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/897) to discuss the gradient, but I don't understand why return None is good

```
numa = tf.constant(5.3)  
res1 = numa * 2   
res2 = tf.floor(numa *2)   
print tf.gradients(res1, numa)
# <type 'list'>: [<tf.Tensor 'gradients/mul_grad/Reshape:0' shape=() dtype=float32>]

print tf.gradients(res2, numa)
# None
```

Can I modify `math_grad.py` directly? need other action?
something like delete `math_grad.pyc`?

```
@ops.RegisterGradient("Floor")
def _FloorGrad(_, unused_grad):
  # return [None]  # before
  return [unused_grad] # I want to modify
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TensorFlow uses `None` to represent `0` for implementation reasons. I don't think it would help you if the returned gradient was true gradient `0`, since you want to train. You could use `gradient_override_map` to substitute gradient of `Identity` op for `Floor` as follows

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
x = tf.Variable(10.)
with tf.get_default_graph().gradient_override_map({"Floor": "Identity"}):
    x2 = tf.floor(x)
loss = tf.square(x2)
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
train_op = opt.minimize(loss)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for i in range(10):
    print(sess.run([loss, train_op]))
```